# Importing a contact column into Podio

Tags: podio

Which app_id should be used for importing into a contact column?  Also, what should the mappings parameter look like?

```
podio.ImporterService.ImportAppItems(fileId, appId, new List<ImportMappingField> {
    new ImportMappingField { FieldId = primaryFieldId, Unique = false, Value = new { column_id = "0" }},
    new ImportMappingField { FieldId = contactfieldId, Unique = false, Value = new { column_id = "1", app_id = ???, mappings = new []{ ??? }}}
})
```

Edit:

I figured it out.  Below is an example that works for me.

```
podio.ImporterService.ImportAppItems(373063497, 18803129, new List<ImportMappingField> {
    new ImportMappingField {
        FieldId = 148580608,
        Unique = false,
        Value = new { column_id = "0" }
    },
    new ImportMappingField {
        FieldId = 148580614,
        Unique = false,
        Value = new {
            mappings = new []{
                new {
                    field_key = "mail",
                    unique = "true",
                    column_id = "4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the API documentation [1]

[1] https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer the question.  Unfortunately, that does not provide any insight towards what the mapping property should look like.  I updated my question to provide more details.  Could you provide a working example of how to import CSV file that includes a contact field?  In my case I'm wanting to set the "Assigned To" field on new imported data.

Comment: While this doesn't quite answer the question, that documentation helped.